# Converting a MySQL result into a JSON string in C

Tags: mysql, c, json

How do I convert a result from a MySQL query to a JSON string in C?

Of course I know how to do it, I just wondered if there's already a solution to copy-paste, realizing I don't want to write boiler-plate code.

And how do I Google for this question? Google just disregard the `c` and shows results for PHP etc.

Comment: http://json.org/, scroll down for a LONG list of languages/libraries.

Comment: @MarcB You mean `json-c`? How would that help me convert a `MYSQL_ROW`?

Comment: Using one of the C libraries, you'd iterate over each row in the result set, creating JSON-formatted data using the column name information and the returned value. The main issues are going to be about where you want the string stored (which code will allocate it; which code will free it, etc).  Maybe you would want a version of the code to write to file as it goes, rather than storing the whole string in memory.  So, you should be able to write a generic function (or a set of them) that works with your chosen JSON library and MySQL.

Comment: A Google search for 'mysql json' shows that there is a lot of information about handling JSON in MySQL available on the web.  There is even built-in support in MySQL 5.7.

Comment: @OlleHärstedt: at some point you need to learn how to use basic tools, and figure out how those basic tools can be strung together to produce complicated results. e.g. start with the mysql [C api](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api.html), figure out how to get a result string out of mysql, which you can then feed into a json library.

Comment: you'll never find `str = json_encode_result_from_mysql_query('SELECT * FROM foo')`, but why should be there be when it could `str = json_encode(fetch_first_row(mysql_query('SELECT * FROM foo')))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C file I made to do this is four times faster than the corresponding PHP file, using `ab` to measure performance:

```
ab -k -c 300 -n 10000 localhost/tiny.php 
Time per request:       393.072 [ms] (mean)
```

With C:

```
ab -k -c 300 -n 10000 localhost/cgi/tiny.fcgi
Time per request:       98.237 [ms] (mean)
```

This is assuming Apache spawns 10 processes of `tiny.fcgi`, and PHP does not use FastCGI.

```
FastCgiServer /var/www/cgi/tiny.fcgi -processes 10
```

This is the PHP code, which connects to MySQL, fetch a query result and echo the JSON representation:

```
<?php

$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "db");

mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, "utf8");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM table");
$rows = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
```

Let's step through the C code. I will use the PHP internal struct `smart_str` to handle strings (this is what PHP use in the `json_encode` function). Using the naive `char*` for strings will be catastrophical, because the number of `malloc` and `free` will be huge due to string append usage.

We want to use FastCGI:

```
#include "fcgi_stdio.h"

int main(void)
{
  while(FCGI_Accept() >= 0)
  {
  }
  FCGI_Finish();
  return 0;
}
```

Analysing this with `valgrind` gives 768 bytes still reachable at end, which we will ignore (bug in FastCGI probably).

Next comes MySQL connection and query:

```
MYSQL*  connection = NULL;
MYSQL_RES* result = NULL;

connection = mysql_init(NULL);

if (connection == NULL)
{
  (void) FCGI_fprintf(FCGI_stderr, "Could not connect to MySQL: %s\n", mysql_error(connection));
  continue;
}

// Connect to database
if (mysql_real_connect(connection, "localhost", "user", "password", "db", 0, NULL, 0) == NULL) 
{
  close_mysql_with_error(connection);
  continue;
}

// Select from pages
if (mysql_query(connection, "SELECT * FROM table") != 0)
{
  close_mysql_with_error(connection);
  continue;
}

// Get result
result = mysql_store_result(connection);

// Abort if no result
if (result == NULL)
{
  close_mysql_with_error(connection);
  continue;
}
```

(I use `continue` instead of `exit` or `return`, because this code is within the `while` loop seen above.)

Nothing strange here, right?

The next part will create our `smart_str` JSON variable, pass it to function `result_to_json` and then echo the result.

```
smart_str json = {0, 0, 0};
result_to_json(result, &json);
if (json.c != NULL)
  (void) FCGI_printf("json = %s\n", json.c);
smart_str_free(&json);
```

The `result_to_json` is just a loop over the rows in the MySQL result:

```
static void result_to_json(MYSQL_RES *result, smart_str* json)
{

  MYSQL_ROW row;

  int i;
  int num_fields = (int) mysql_num_fields(result);
  smart_str** fields = get_field_names(result, num_fields);

  if (fields == NULL)
  {
    return;
  }

  smart_str_appendc(json, '[');

  while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result, num_fields)))
  {
    smart_str_appendl(json, "{", 1);

    for (i = 0; i < num_fields; i++)
    {
      // key
      smart_str_appendl(json, "\"", 1);
      smart_str_appendl(json, fields[i]->c, fields[i]->len);
      smart_str_appendl(json, "\": ", 3);

      if (row[i] == NULL)
      {
        smart_str_appendl(json, "null", 4);
        smart_str_appendl(json, ", ", 2);
      }
      else
      {
        smart_str_appendl(json, "\"", 1);
        smart_str_appendl(json, row[i], strlen(row[i]));
        smart_str_appendl(json, "\", ", 3);
      }

    }

    if (json == NULL) {
      free_field_names(fields, num_fields);
      return;
    }

    // Strip last ','
    json->len--;
    json->len--;

    smart_str_appendl(json, "}, ", 3);
  }

  if (json == NULL)
  {
    free_field_names(fields, num_fields);
    return;
  }

  // Strip last ','
  json->len--;
  json->len--;

  smart_str_appendl(json, "]", 1);
  smart_str_0(json);

  free_field_names(fields, num_fields);

  return;
}
```

Finally, `get_field_names` and `free_field_names`:

```
static smart_str** get_field_names(MYSQL_RES *my_result, int num_fields)
{
  smart_str** fields;   // Array of pointers
  MYSQL_FIELD *field = NULL;
  int i;

  // Allocate size of array
  fields = malloc(num_fields * sizeof(smart_str*));

  if (fields == NULL) 
  {
    return NULL;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < num_fields; i++)
  {
    field = mysql_fetch_field(my_result);

    if (field == NULL) {
      // TODO: Free fields[]
      free(fields);
      return NULL;
    }

    fields[i] = malloc(sizeof(smart_str));

    if (fields[i] == NULL) {
      // TODO: Free fields[]
      free(fields);
      return NULL;
    }
    else 
    {
      fields[i]->c = NULL;
      smart_str_appendl(fields[i], field->name, strlen(field->name));
    }

  return fields;

}

static void free_field_names(smart_str** strings, int size)
{

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    smart_str_free(strings[i]);
    free(strings[i]);
  }

  free(strings);

}
```

There you go! What's left to do is to measure against FastCGI enabled PHP, to see how much the PHP performance improves.

Comment: You can skip FastCGI and make an apache module, make it even faster :)

Comment: @Dan Nice, you have a link for that?

Comment: I used this example https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/developer/modguide.html and then used the Jansson C library to output json. https://jansson.readthedocs.io/en/latest/